# Delphi: adequate data structure for headered blocks

Tags: delphi, stream, header, record, dereference

As far as I know one of the most used data structure cannot represented by an adequate dta structure directly: we speak about **blocks or streams with header.**

Let's imagine a simple image format, where the first integer represents the kind of image (Grayscale, RGB, CMYK etc.), the second the bit depth, the third and fourth the width and height respectively, and all the subsequent bytes represent the bitmap data itself.

Something like this:

```
TSimpleImage = packed record
  imageType: integer;
  bitDepth: integer;
  width: integer;
  height: integer;
  data: array [0 .. high(integer)] of byte; // actual image data with variable length;
end;
```

Of course, as we cannot predict the size in compile time we define the maximum possible value here.
The problem is that even if this structure is perfect usable, it's neither elegant nor safe. That is, it never can be used directly, just dereferenced, or passing as `var` or `const` variable to a procedure – but *obviously no compile warnings or errors will occur when we accidentally omit this rule.*

Is there something more elegant which can be used for headers + blocks (data streams)?

**UPDATE:**
*It seems that the term 'stream' is a little ambigous here. A stream doesn't need necessarily to be something like `TStream` which have to get read sequentially. It can reside in memory as well, e.g. as part of a RAM window of an MMF. So there is no sequential reading here, all the byte of the block or stream can be accessed immediately and randomly.*

Comment: That's a problem which doesn't have to be one: either you treat everything as `TStream` or `TBytes` and then just read off the first 16 bytes as "header" record, or you make the stream or dynamic array the last member of your record. [`TStream.Read( Header, SizeOf( Header ) )`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TStream.Read) works well - no need to force both into exactly one record.

Comment: This data zone might already be somewhere in the RAM, hence `Tstream` and the `read` method has to do nothing with this problem. You have the address of the beginning of the header and that's it. So the only chance to access the structure is to use a `^TSimpleImage` pointer.

Comment: So why don't you read the header first and then calculate the size of the data based on information stored inside the header. That is the purpose of the headers.

Comment: I can see you still don't understand the problem. The 'stream' term might be a little ambigous: a stream (or block) might already reside in memory, thus can be accessed RANDOMLY, no need to “read” the header first. There are many cases when even calculating the exact size of the data structure is not just simple. But even so, how you can define such a data structure DYNAMICALLY? Dynamic arrays are totally inadequate for this, due to their internal structure.